# Why is my javascript code not updating any text from html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning the basics of JavaScript and am working on a rock paper scissors game but can't seem to get the scores or the main prompt to update. Is there something specific that needs updating or is the JavaScript just written incorrectly? I took a tutorial I found and followed that but changed it to fit my project so I am thinking I possibly just didn't adapt the code properly.

```js
const game = () => {
  let pScore = 0;
  let cScore = 0;

  //play match
  const playMatch = () => {
    const options = document.querySelectorAll(".controls button");
    const playerHand = document.querySelector(".player-hand");
    const compHand = document.querySelector(".comp-hand");
    const hands = document.querySelectorAll(".hands img");

    hands.forEach(hand => {
      hand.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
        this.style.animation = "";
      });
    });
    //Computer Options
    const compOptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

    options.forEach(option => {
      option.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //Computer choice
        const compNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        const compChoice = compOptions[compNumber];

        setTimeout(() => {
          //Here is where we call compare hands
          compareHands(this.textContent, compChoice);
          //Update images
          playerHand.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000ff`;
          compHand.src = `https://via.placeholder.com/50/ff0000`;
        }, 1000);

        // Animation
        playerHand.style.animation = 'shakePlayer 1s ease';
        compHand.style.animation = 'shakeComputer 1s ease'
      });
    });
  };

  const updateScore = () => {
    const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score p");
    const compScore = document.querySelector(".comp-score p");
    playerScore.textContent = pScore;
    compScore.textContent = cScore;
  };

  const compareHands = (playerChoice, compChoice) => {
    //Update text
    const winner = document.querySelector(".title");
    //We are checking for a tie
    if (playerChoice === compChoice) {
      winner.textContent = 'Tie';
      return;
    }
    //check for ROCK
    if (playerChoice === "rock") {
      if (compChoice === "scissors") {
        winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
    //Check for PAPER
    if (playerChoice === "paper") {
      if (compChoice === "scissors") {
        winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
    //check for SCISSORS
    if (playerChoice === "scissors") {
      if (compChoice === "rock") {
        winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
        cScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      } else {
        winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
        pScore++;
        updateScore();
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  playMatch();
};
//start the game function
game();
```

```html
<section class="game grid">
  <h2 class="title">A Simple Game of Choice...</h2>

  <div class="scores grid">
    <div class="player-score">
      <h3>Player:</h3>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comp-score">
      <h3>Computer:</h3>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hands grid">
    <img class="player-hand" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="image of a hand forming a rock">
    <img class="comp-hand" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="image of a hand forming a rock">
  </div>


  <div class="controls grid">
    <button class="rock">ROCK</button>
    <button class="paper">PAPER</button>
    <button class="scissors">SCISSORS</button>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Please, in your next questions, try to investigate more, debug your code carefully and trace the expected scenario to check where is the unexpected behaviour happens exactly, by doing so, I found that you are getting the text for the player from the content whch is capitalized, and for the compChoice you have an array of lowe case words, so, all your if conditions doesn't work, you can unify them, for example by using `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Also, after debugging and knowing where the problem happens, if you still can't fix it, add only the needed part with a better description for the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was the first question I've asked here and a few comments said to only leave the part of the code I am having the issue with so now I know for future questions. I was honestly unsure where I went wrong but could have certainly narrowed down the code to a snippet

Comment: Thank you for understanding, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your text values in the buttons are uppercase, whereas the comp values are all lowercase.

You can either change their case in the buttons, or in javascript convert to lowercase.

```js
const game = () => {
    let pScore = 0;
    let cScore = 0;
  
    //play match
    const playMatch = () => {
       const options = document.querySelectorAll(".controls button");
       const playerHand = document.querySelector(".player-hand");
       const compHand = document.querySelector(".comp-hand");
       const hands = document.querySelectorAll(".hands img");
 
       hands.forEach(hand => {
         hand.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
            this.style.animation = "";
         });
       });
       //Computer Options
       const compOptions = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
 
       options.forEach(option => {
          option.addEventListener("click", function() {
           //Computer choice
           const compNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
           const compChoice = compOptions[compNumber];
 
    setTimeout(() => {
     //Here is where we call compare hands
        compareHands(this.textContent.toLowerCase(), compChoice);
        //Update images
      console.log("compareHands a", this.textContent);
      console.log("compareHands b", compChoice);
        playerHand.src = `./img/${this.textContent}.png`;
        compHand.src = `./img/${compChoice}.png`;
      }, 1000);
          
          // Animation
           playerHand.style.animation = 'shakePlayer 1s ease';
           compHand.style.animation = 'shakeComputer 1s ease'
          });
       });
    };
 
    const updateScore = () => {
      console.log("updateScore");
      const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score p");
      const compScore = document.querySelector(".comp-score p");
      playerScore.textContent = pScore;
      compScore.textContent = cScore;
      console.log("pScore", pScore);
    };
 
    const compareHands = (playerChoice, compChoice) => {
     //Update text
     const winner = document.querySelector(".title");
     //We are checking for a tie
      if(playerChoice === compChoice) {
       winner.textContent = 'Tie';
       return;
      }
      //check for ROCK
      if(playerChoice === "rock") {
         if(compChoice === "scissors") {
          winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
          pScore++;
          updateScore();
          return;
         } else {
          winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
          cScore++;
          updateScore();
          return;
         }
      }
      //Check for PAPER
     if (playerChoice === "paper") {
      if (compChoice === "scissors") {
       winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
       cScore++;
       updateScore();
       return;
      } else {
       winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
       pScore++;
       updateScore();
       return;
      }
     }
     //check for SCISSORS
     if (playerChoice === "scissors") {
      if (compChoice === "rock") {
       winner.textContent = "Computer Wins";
       cScore++;
       updateScore();
       return;
      } else {
       winner.textContent = "Player Wins";
       pScore++;
       updateScore();
       return;
      }
     }
    };
    playMatch();
 };
 //start the game function
 game();
```

```html
<body>
   
    <section class="game grid">
        <h2 class="title">A Simple Game of Choice...</h2>

        <div class="scores grid">
            <div class="player-score">
              <h3>Player:</h3>
              <p>0</p>
            </div>
            <div class="comp-score">
              <h3>Computer:</h3>
              <p>0</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hands grid">
            <img class="player-hand" src="/img/rock.png" alt="image of a hand forming a rock">
            <img class="comp-hand" src="/img/rock.png" alt="image of a hand forming a rock">
        </div>
        
          
         <div class="controls grid">
                <button class="rock">ROCK</button>
                <button class="paper">PAPER</button>
                <button class="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
                
          </div>

    </section> 
</body>
```